# Relation between eigenvectors and singular vectors of complex skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, skew-symmetric-matrices

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1439614/173147), if $A$ is a *real* skew-symmetric matrix, and $v,w$ are a pair of orthogonal singular vectors with
$$Av=sw \qquad\text{ and }\qquad Aw=-sv,$$
for some $s>0$, then the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$ are $v\pm iw$ (with eigenvalues $\pm is$).

However, as discussed for example in these notes ([Link to pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/webpage/pfaffian2.pdf)), one can state more generally that for any (possibly complex) skew-symmetric $A$ there is a unitary $U$ such that $U^TAU$ is block diagonal:

$$U^T A U = \operatorname{diag}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0 & m_1 \\ -m_1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & m_2 \\ -m_2 & 0\end{pmatrix},..., \begin{pmatrix}0 & m_n \\ -m_n & 0\end{pmatrix},\boldsymbol0\right\}.$$
In analogy with the above statement about the real case, this can be seen as equivalent to stating that the singular vectors of $A$ can be organised as pairs $v_k,w_k$ such that
$$Av_k=s_kw_k \qquad\text{ and }\qquad Aw_k^*=-s_kv_k^*.$$
However, now $v_k\pm iw_k$ aren't always eigenvectors.

Is there a general relation between eigenvectors and singular vectors in the complex case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There cannot be any such relation for generic complex matrices, because a skew-symmetric complex matrice need not be diagonalisable.
For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
is not diagonalisable.
Its singular values still pair as per the mentioned result: they are $0$ and $\pm\sqrt2$; however, the $\pm\sqrt2$ do not correspond to any eigenvector.